# Unable to upload Image - Codeigniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Cannot upload image using CI upload library. It shows no error though. Can I use other name for the `function do_upload()`? And if it's possible then do I need to change do_upload part in this line? `$this->upload->do_upload();`

```
//Upload library and file helper defined in autoload.//

function updatemember($id)
{ 
if($this->input->post('imagefull_org')) {

    $config['upload_path'] ='./assets/upload/members'; 
    $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config["file_name"] = $this->input->post('imagefull_org');
    $config["max_size"] = 2048;
    $config["max_width"] = 400;
    $config["max_height"] = 400;
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $datai = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    //print_r($datai);exit();
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {               
        $this->session->set_flashdata('ok_message',$this->upload->display_errors());}     
}
//codes...
}
```

View:
Here is what my view looks like.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group"> 
                <?php echo form_label('Organization logo')?>
                <?php echo form_upload('imagefull_org')?><br/><span class="display_message">&nbsp;Image Size must be 200 X 200px (less than 2MB)</span>
                <?php if(!empty($u->imagefull_org)){?>
                <?php echo form_hidden('imagechk_org', $u->imagefull_org)?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/upload/members/'.$u->imagefull_org?>" width="50px"/>               
                <br><p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;color: #2A4D79;">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url().'account/imgunlink/'.$u->id.'/'.$u->imagefull_org.'/'.'imagefull_org'?>" class="btn">Delete Image</a></p>
                <?php }?>              
            </div>
```

End

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the docs to see if you're properly structuring your code as it should? Without any errors, it's really a hard job to debug a problem, especially when we don't have enaugh (I mean every detail) information about your code.

Comment: You have the the correct rights on ./assets/upload/members? Did you tried to use error_reporting function to see what error do you get? What webserver logs says?

Comment: It might be permission issue to the folder.

Comment: Sorry, permission issue is not the problem.

Comment: Show the complete upload form, instead of only part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use

```
form_open_multipart()
```

And try to set filename to

```
$config["file_name"] = $_FILES["imagefull_org"]["name"];
```

Finally,

```
$this->upload->do_upload('imagefull_org');
```

**Edit**

Try to check

```
if (isset($_FILES["imagefull_org"])) {

}
```

instead of

```
if ($this->input->post('imagefull_org')) {

}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the parameter in
 
`$this->upload->do_upload()` function
try this 
`$this->upload->do_upload('imagefull_org')`
other wise problem in 
`$config["file_name"] = $this->input->post('imagefull_org')`
try to give other way of image name if first solution is not work

sorry but i'm not having more reputation so I can give comment.

Comment: its not working. I tried both $this->upload->do_upload('imagefull_org') as well as $this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('imagefull_org'))

Comment: @NostalgicMirazAryal please try my now solution and first also check you have not forgot `form_open_multipart()` for form create.